# Manually entering URL in built project, while already being on a subpage leads to distortion of styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, service-worker

I have a React project, that is nearly finished. So naturally I build it and configured my nginx server to host it.

For building I used react-snap (no serverside rendering applied here).

Now I have this really strange behavior I noticed. When I browse on my site, everything runs smooth and is fine. I can use all kinds of links on the site without problems. Reloading with Ctrl+R works fine as well. But as soon as I don't use any link on the page and don't open another tab (or make a browserreload of the used tab), but manually type in another urlpath of my site in the browser, while being on the site (any supage of the site really), it kind of crashes.

By crashes I mean, elements get completely distorted. It's like they are loaded on top of each other. Now the strange part of it is the fact, that this doesn't happen in dev, but only when I use the static files I build for prod.
Can someone recognise the source of this strange behaviour?

I mean it obviously has something to do with loading a subroute without using an internal link, while no full reload is performed.

I can provide as much additional information as necessary, if anyone may have a clue, where this behavior could come from. But really I don't know where to start, so I reduced the question to the pure description of what's happening.

Comment: Okay due to a hint from a friendly coder I came to realize, that the Service Worker is actually causing the issue.
Every time the main.js (and other files) is served by the Service Worker, the rendering crashes and the browser displays the described error. (Caching)

Comment: By disabling the service worker the problem was indeed solved. But I still don't really know, what caused the caching issues.